# Debugging fiiled on tizen studio

Tags: tizen-native-app, tizen-studio

While Debugging my native tizen application I got: below message.

"Cannot launch application with GDBServer.
The application (v4tl19rMr7) is not running on 000007b62e9ce213"

Can Any one help.
I am using Tizen Studio: 1.0

Comment: Is your debugger properly installed ?

Comment: Please Check your debugger version at Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Tizen Settings.

Comment: I tried with both GNU-4.9 and LLVM-GCC-4.6 tool chains. There is no difference. I can still see the problem. Are you able to debug it. Create any native app and do debug as. Do you get GDB error?

Comment: Can you run the application without error ?

I have tried those tool chains (debugger version is GNU gdb 7.8.1) and successfully debugged native app (both emulator and device).

I have not found any GDB error. I am using Tizen Studio 1.0.1.

Comment: I am able to debug on emulator. The problem is with device I can not debug.

Comment: Can you provide more information ? i.e. more log , device name etc?